# Insert new timestamp value to acc table in kamailio

Tags: sql, config, kamailio

I want to add a new column to `acc` table. I created a new column in the `acc` table of type timestamp and named it `ring_time`. In every call I put the ring time to a `$dlg_var` like this:

```
$dlg_var(ringtime) = $Ts;
```

Then I add a extra column in config like this:

```
modparam("acc", "log_extra", "src_user=$fU;src_domain=$fd;src_ip=$si;" "dst_ouser=$tU;dst_user=$rU;dst_domain=$rd;ring_time=$dlg_var(ringtime)")
```

but when I try to test it, I always get:

```
db_mysql [km_dbase.c:122]: db_mysql_submit_query(): driver error on query: Incorrect datetime value: '1591361996' for column kamailio.acc.ring_time at row 1 (1292) 
Jun 5 17:29:59 kamailio /usr/sbin/kamailio[22901]: ERROR: {2 102 INVITE 105a0f4a3d99a0a5558355e54b43f4e1@192.168.1.121:5060} <core> [db_query.c:244]: db_do_insert_cmd(): error while submitting query
Jun 5 17:29:59 kamailio /usr/sbin/kamailio[22901]: ERROR: {2 102 INVITE 105a0f4a3d99a0a5558355e54b43f4e1@192.168.1.121:5060} acc [acc.c:477]: acc_db_request(): failed to insert into database
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an error with the SQL INSERT query, if I had to guess I'd say you're being caught out by the date format in the SQL table not matching the date format you're pushing to it.

I don't know the structure of your database, but there's a simple trick I use for debugging SQL queries when I can't see the query being run;

Start up Wireshark/TCPdump on the machine and packet capture for all SQL traffic (MySQL is port 3306) and replicate the error.
From the packet capture and you'll be able to see the Query Kamailio's database engine ran.

Answer (score 0):

If the error "db_mysql [km_dbase.c:122]: db_mysql_submit_query(): driver error on query: Incorrect datetime value: '1591361996' for column kamailio.acc.ring_time at row 1 (1292)", the '1591361996' looks like it is an epoch for the $dlg_var(ringtime).  The "Incorrect datetime value" part of the error looks like the database is trying to store the value in datetime data type so a data type mismatch.  Double-check and you may need either change the ringtime to convert to datetime or change the database column to a type that will take epoch.